# Run default mail client

Tags: bash, email, mail, alternative

To run the default web browser or terminal there are commands like `x-www-browser` and `x-terminal-emulator`. There are other alternatives for common programs.

Is there a similar command to run the default email client?

As an alternative, is there a way to execute the mailto protocol handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the default email client, but with a new message window open with this commands:

```
xdg-email
```

or

```
xdg-open mailto://
```

Both support some options to compose the new message or a standard mailto url. xdg-email also supports attachments, cc and bcc fields.

```
gnome-open mailto://
```

Will also work, but it's only supported under gnome.

Comment: So there is no way to open just the client and not a new message window as well?

Comment: Not that I know. You can check the xdg-email source, it's a bash script. It basically finds the .desktop file associated with "x-scheme-handler/mailto", and from it extracts the binary.

Comment: Not looking likely unless I rewrite it. It also seems the solution differs depending on the distro... But I haven't looked in too much detail as it can't do what I want. Opening with the message window is sufficient (though not ideal) so unless there is a miracle solution this would seem to be the answer.

Comment: xdg-open is a standard, and at least it works in Ubuntu, Arch and Fedora. I believe that it will likely work in most distributions.

Comment: Yes, but I was referring to the internal code, which has specific code for some distros. You can add to that list that it works with CrunchBang as well.

Comment: Oh, yes. The code is not only distro-specific, it's also de specific. If you have something strange (errr... I mean funny), it won't work.

Comment: In any event, xdg-email is the best way to go. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I took the relevant function from xdg-email, added some explanatory comments, and made some tweaks. The result does what OP needed--simply launches default email client. Four years too late, perhaps, but better late than never.

http://pastebin.com/WuEMAJh9

Comment: Adding your code inline is recommended, in case the link gets destroyed or lost.